# AWS IAM role not working with Elasticsearch 5.0.0-alpha2, but works with 2.3 version

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to use AWS IAM role with Elasticsearch 5.0.0-alpha2 and EC2 discovery plug-in, but it does not seem to be working and I am getting below error:

> "Exception while retrieving instance list from AWS API: Authorization
>   header or parameters are not formatted correctly. (Service: AmazonEC2;
>   Status Code: 401; Error Code: AuthFailure"

I am using below configuration with jdk8:

```
 cluster.name: "test-cluster"
 cloud.aws.region: "us-west-2"
 cloud.aws.ec2.region: "us-west-2"
 cloud.aws.ec2.protocol: "http"
 discovery.type: "ec2"
 #bootstrap.mlockall: true
 node.master: true
 node.data: false
 node.name: ${HOSTNAME}-Master
 discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
 network.host: _ec2:privateIp_
 discovery.ec2.any_group: true
 discovery.ec2.groups : sg-9d856tfe
```

However, same configuration works fine with with Elasticsearch 2.3 version. Has anyone faced the same issue with the latest Elasticsearch version 5.0.0-alpha2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in their latest version. I raised this as a bug in their elasticsearch repo on github. Seems they have fixed this issue now.  Please refer to below link for details:
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/18652

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/aws-iam-role-not-working-with-elasticsearch-5-0-0-alpha2-but-works-with-2-3-version/51347